# IE 8 not showing button created dynamically inside a table in a row

Tags: jquery, html, button

I am trying to create a button dynamically in a row inside a table but in ie 8 it is not showing button

here is my code

```
$("#mytable tr:eq("+i+")").append("<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"delete_row\" id=\"delete_row\" value=\"delete\"style=\"margin-left:25px\"/></td></tr>");
```

where i is the index of row.

Comment: Which version of jquery you using?

Comment: The ID delete_row is unique? It looks like that all rows can have a button with the ID delete_row.

Comment: can u post the error on the page (it is present in the lower bar of IE browser)

Comment: @ssilas777 im using 1.4.2 version

Comment: @s4ty even after removing id attribute there is no change ,it is still not showing the dynamic button

Comment: @CodeHunter it is not showing any error

Comment: please help i dont know what to do even after changing the version there is not any difference in the result

Comment: at the end of the append u r adding </tr> is that necessary

Comment: @CodeHunter yeah because that is the end of row and i am adding rows dynamically

Comment: @CodeHunter thanks brother after removing </tr> tag it is showing the button but i didnt understand the logic behind it please enlighten me

Comment: You are not adding rows dynamically (at least not in that line of code). Your code adds a table cell (`td`) to the ì`-th row, which already exists and thus is already "closed".

Comment: @RoToR i is the index of the row which is always 1 less than the no of rows so if already 2 rows are present and i trying to add 3rd row i am getting the length of the rows and then i am making use of index so that for the third row index will be 2 (3-1)

Comment: the least u could hav done with that help is that u should hav upvoted it ;) @anubhav

Comment: @anubhav It doesn't work like that. `eq()` selects an existing row. It never creates a new row.